# Obter informação de outro programa usando Python

Tags: python, memória

Olá, gostaria de saber como é possível eu obter informações de um outro programa usando Python. Em questão, eu quero desenvolver um contador de blinds para o PokerStars.

Nota: blinds no poker é o conjunto das apostas obrigatórias: big e small blind.

Exemplo:

1. Eu entro em um torneio de poker, consequentemente recebo um quantidade de fichas (stack);
2. O nível de blinds do torneio é mutável, ou seja, vai aumentando conforme o tempo vai passando;
3. Meu objetivo é pegar o número de fichas que possuo e dividir pelo valor do big blind, obtendo assim o meu número de blinds.

Em resumo, quero saber como "localizar" a informação das quantidades das minhas fichas, assim como o nível de blind atual na memória. Então dividir o primeiro pelo o segundo.

Figura: a) Cenário normal do jogo. Valores do blinds: Big Blind = 100; Small Blind = 50. b) Como o programa deve agir. Se o blind está em 100/50, então é o mesmo que eu dizer 1/0.5 e dividir a quantidade de fichas totais por o valor do big blind.

[image: a) Cenário normal do jogo. Valores do blinds: Big Blind = 100; Small Blind = 50. b) Como o programa deve agir. Se o blind está em 100/50, então é o mesmo que eu dizer 1/0.5 e dividir a quantidade de fichas totais por o valor do big blind.]

Existem diversos programas que realizam essa tarefa (e outras mais complexas), porém todos são pagos.

Comment: Você tem a API do PokerStars?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado PokerStars não oferece nenhuma API pública.